# Could the universe really be expanding at a constant rate?

Tags: experimental-physics, universe, space-expansion, dark-energy

I was just thinking, sorry if this idea is idiotic, but since we know galaxies move away from each other at an accelerating rate, could this be due to a weakening gravitational force between galaxies? For example, if the universe is expanding at a constant rate and galaxies started off moving away more slowly due to the stronger gravitational attraction but as they move further and further away they lose more and more of their gravitational attraction, resulting in a greater and greater speed until the gravitational attraction is insignificant resulting in some kind of speed limit as the galaxies approach an infinite distance away. Again sorry if this idea is completely wrong, constructive criticism is welcomed! Also sorry for the run on sentence.

Comment: yes I am familiar with dark energy, I'm not saying the universe expands because of weakening gravitational forces, i'm just posing a theory for the accelerated distance between galaxies.

Comment: 1. We do not really know that the distance between galaxies is accelerated because the expansion of the universe, this is just a theory to explain accelerated distances between galaxies 2. Yes, my theory would attribute accelerated distances between galaxies to the expansion of the universe. 3. there are things wrong with dark energy theory, such as the main question about it-where is the energy coming from and why?- 4.People prove accepted things wrong all the time, hence the word "accepted" rather than the word "true" 5. Really all I wanted to know was why is this theory incorrect (physics

Comment: wise)  because someone probably has suggested it before

Comment: There was an alternative giant void cosmology that could explain observed acceleration without the dark energy, but it needed the distribution of matter in the universe to be highly uneven with Earth in a very special place. http://blogs.discovermagazine.com/cosmicvariance/2010/07/29/are-you-the-center-of-the-universe/#.Vr0K3uaE6ex I think it was since ruled out though.

Answer (score 1):

> Could the universe really be expanding at a constant rate?

Everything is possible I suppose, but the evidence suggests the universe is expanding at an accelerating rate, see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accelerating_expansion_of_the_universe). This came as something of a surprise in 1998.

> I was just thinking, sorry if this idea is idiotic, but since we know galaxies move away from each other at an accelerating rate, could this be due to a weakening gravitational force between galaxies?

No. If you had two planetary bodies moving apart, gravitational force between them reduces, but that doesn't make them move apart faster. You need something else for this.

> For example, if the universe is expanding at a constant rate and galaxies started off moving away more slowly due to the stronger gravitational attraction but as they move further and further away they lose more and more of their gravitational attraction, resulting in a greater and greater speed until the gravitational attraction is insignificant resulting in some kind of speed limit as the galaxies approach an infinite distance away. Again sorry if this idea is completely wrong, constructive criticism is welcomed! Also sorry for the run on sentence.

The point you're missing is that *space* expands. Check out the [raisin-cake analogy](https://www.google.co.uk/#q=raisin+cake+analogy). The galaxies are like the raisins. Even if they all attracted one another and ended up in the centre of the cake, the cake is still expanding.